# Force using WAP for a Http Request

Tags: php, html, http-request, wap

i readed a lot about deciding if the client uses WAP or not to deliver the right website. But what I want to do is to force the Client to send the Http Request via WAP if its possible to use WAP. I dont know how to do it, but I know that its possible. 
Does anyone know, how to force a mobile client to use WAP when it connects normaly to the server, or how to create a link to a WAP connection to some server ? 
Thanks for every answer, I'm googleing since a few hours now and I've really found nothing like this :c

PS:I'm talking about the Wireless Application Protocol just so you dont understand me wrong.

Comment: why would you want to use wap in the first place? wap rightfully belongs in the garbage heap of the past...

Comment: yeah i know, but a wap request contains things like the msisdn.

Comment: The http request also contains this things - but this depends on the network

Comment: No it doesnt, i tried many times. But thats not my question i just want to do it